# How to revert reactions from GetStream.io feed

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I have a question about the getStream.io NodeJS reaction API.

So I would like to build a comment system. However the comments should be loaded and displayed in the order oldest -> newest.

In the documentation I found out that I can retrieve a reaction around a certain reaction id by filtering with the parameters `d_gt` or `d_lt`.

But I think this is not the right way.
Is there an efficient way to retrieve the reactions starting with very first reaction and not with the most recent?

I appreciate every response.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, latest reactions are enriched from the feed, you can use filter API by giving an activity id to load them chronologically.

```js
const response = await client.reactions.filter({ 
  'activity_id': yourActivityId, 
  'kind': 'comment', 
  'id_gt': yourLastId,
  'limit': 10, 
});
```

Comment: But for this method, I need the id of my very first comment created, right?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and just discovered that passing the activity_id as filter param retrieves reactions sorted from oldest to newest :
`id_gt => activity_id`

> Reactions are returned in descending order (newest to oldest) by default and when using id_lt[e] , and in ascending order (oldest to newest) when using id_gt[e].

So you can pass either reaction_id to load next reactions using limit or use activity id to load first reactions.